# How to access mongodb from all models in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, model

I'm building my node project from scratch for the first time and I want to know how can I get access to db object from all models files ?

My project are structured like that :

```
 project/
  |-> controllers/
  |   |-> auth.js
  |
  |-> lib/
  |-> models/
  |   |-> token.js  
  |   |-> user.js
  |
  |-> views/
  |-> app.js
```

For now, the mongo connection is started on app.js, when the user make a request to the server and the db object is storage on req to can access from controller, ..

```
// Set db on req
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.db = mongoskin.db( /* connect string */ );
  next();
});
```

*Now the problem:* When i'm on a controller, I can make query using req.bd object. But I want use the db only on my models, so I have to pass this object each time i'm require a model..

Do I have a better solution ? Model must connect to the database ? Or I'm completely wrong ?

Thank for helping !

---

*Bonus question:* What's the best for db connection ?

- Create one when server start and keep it all the time ?
- *Actual*: Create one when user make a request and use it only the this request ?

Comment: this may answer your bonus question: http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign it to app instead, though, i would instead make a module out of it.

mongodb.js

```
module.exports = mongoskin.db( /* connect string */ );
```

now you can just require it wherever you need it.

```
var db = require('../lib/mongodb');

myModel.myMethod = function () {
    db.doSomething();
};
```

Comment: It's not a problem if I call multiple model on my controller ? So if I call 5 models i'll do 5 connections ?..

Comment: No, this example would only use a single connection app-wide. You can use this same technique and implement connection pooling with it too.

Comment: the module export are not lunch each time you require the lib ? (i'm new in node)

Comment: Nope, the code is only executed the first time. Subsequent times that you require will simply return what was exported.

Comment: module code runs once at load time: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching   Edit: what Kevin B said :)

Comment: Hoo that change everything ! It's more easy like that :p Thank you for your help

Comment: I implement my models this way too, so if i need access to a model i simply require it in rather than having to store it on app.models and pass app around. Very powerful.

Comment: I don't realy know if I understand you when you say "store on app.models" When did you do that ?

Comment: No that's just an alternative to this route, probably not as good as doing it this way